# Scaling Orchard with Azure Web Sites

Tags: azure, orchardcms, azure-web-app-service

I am currently experimenting with installing Orchard on Azure using the recently released "Web Sites" functionality.

I have successfully installed and setup Orchard using the template from the gallery and so far everything seems to be going well.

My question is: If I scale up the site to use 3 instances is there anything special I need to do to ensure that the instances all work from the same cache? So a new page appears on all instances at once.

I have a little experience with Umbraco and I had to push documents and the cache into blob storage for it to work correctly.

Is this already taken care of by the template?

Thanks for your help,

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a guide on the Orchard website](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Deploying-Orchard-to-Windows-Azure) that explains how to deploy to a Windows Azure Web Role (Cloud Service). I haven't seen an implementation for Windows Azure Web Sites that supports more than one reserved instance.

In order to make Orchard work on multiple reserved instances you'll need to configure it to use the AzureBlobStorageProvider, which will make sure files are persisted to blob storage instead of local filesystem. This is how you would configure the [Sites.config](http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/95f0539354b2#src/Orchard.Azure/Orchard.Azure.Web/Config/Sites.config):

```
  <component instance-scope="per-lifetime-scope"
             type="Orchard.Azure.FileSystems.Media.AzureBlobStorageProvider, Orchard.Azure"
             service="Orchard.FileSystems.Media.IStorageProvider">
  </component>
```

In your Global.asax.cs you'll also want to make sure the storage account information is read from the web.config:

```
        CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher(    
            (configName, configSetter) =>    
                configSetter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[configName])    
            );
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Sandrino that's pointed me in the right direction. I think I'll just deploy from web matrix rather than using the template as that will allow me to change the global.asax. Will this also work for the cache or does this just apply to media files?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy, If you have an existing site in Azure (created through the gallery), do you know how to transfer/move the existing images to the blog storage. Does Orchard take care of this automatically if I just change the configuration?

Comment: Not automatically but there are a few free tools out there that mount Azure blob storage into the file system that you can use to move media around. Azure Web Sites obviously don't need that as they can store media in the media folder like on regular hosts.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Okey, thank you for your answer. It had me worried that there was a chance that the images would get lost if the site was moved as it uses share hosting. *puh* :)