# CPU Spiking on OrchardCMS Azure Website (not webrole) looking to blob storage

Tags: performance, azure, orchardcms, blobstorage

I am experiencing very poor performance.  I have am OrchardCms Template pulled down from Azure, which includes a very little in extra modules and a small ecommerce module I have written.

I have read the performance discussions and am aware of the discussions such as

[Scaling Orchard with Azure Web Sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582947/scaling-orchard-with-azure-web-sites)
[Orchard CMS Speed Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240239/orchard-cms-speed-issues)

I have then looked at the SampleHost.config in the settings with no concrete implementation.

Is it safe to say that if you are wanting any performance you need to go to WebRoles rather than Azure Websites or am I missing something.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19679

Answer (score 0):

Which Web Sites tier are you using? If on *free* tier, then you're sharing the virtual machine instances with other tenants and this can impact performance, especially if you have "noisy neighbors." Once you move to dedicated instances, then performance would be roughly equivalent to what you'd see with Web Roles (Cloud Services). This goes for both compute and bandwidth (and bandwidth is shared between external traffic and traffic between your compute and Storage.

Comment: Thanks for your comment however I am trying to keep costs as low as possible so this is not an option.

Comment: There's also *shared* tier which is cheaper than dedicated tier. I'm not sure I understand your objective of keeping costs low though: you either go free (with restricted performance) or upgrade to higher-performing configuration. There's no scenario letting you boost performance without paying for the resources you're consuming. (Note: MSDN benefits are an exception, as you get up to $150 of monetary credit monthly to spend as you wish).